# How can I display a thumbnail for my website?

Tags: html, facebook, src, meta

When I send my site to someone on Facebook or Messenger, the preview of a website will have the Facebook logo and the description is blank.

It doesn’t show my fav icon it shows the Facebook logo. Example:

[image]

But if I enter the Twitter URL it displays what Twitter wants to show. Example:

[image]

Comment: Set an og:image URL that points to the image you want to be there

Comment: check with https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters

Answer (score 1):

You may use **meta** tags like this:

```
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.yourwebsite.com/some_folder/some_fav_icon.png" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.yourwebsite.com/some_folder/some_fav_icon.png" />
<meta property="og:title" content="Your Title" />
<meta property="og:description" content="Your Description" />
```

Comment: Does it take some time for the changes? I did it and it still shows the facebook logo.

Comment: I did this <meta property="og:url" content="http://www.paltoona.webutu.com/socialmedia/LOGO.png" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.paltoona.webutu.com/socialmedia/LOGO.png" />

Comment: My favicon is in the folder socialmedia and named LOGO.png

Answer (score 0):

Pages that render nicely when shared on Facebook (or other sites) use the Open Graph Protocol. You'll find [this website](http://ogp.me/) helpful